# Retrieving CreatedById from KnowledgeArticleVersion object throws null error

Tags: apex, knowledge

I'm attempting to retrieve the id of a user who created a particular KnowledgeArticleVersion and getting an "attempt to de-reference a null object" error on the line where I add creator to modifiers. Using system debug to print out kavs[0].CreatedById, though, I get

```
15:58:27:020 USER_DEBUG [18]|DEBUG|005i0000000jqkeAAA
```

which is the ID I want and implies that what I'm attempting to add to this list is not null (In this case kavs was of length 1). I even threw in a check for nullity which didn't seem to make a difference.

```
List<KnowledgeArticleVersion> kavs = [SELECT CreatedById FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion WHERE (KnowledgeArticleId = :kas.Id AND PublishStatus = 'online' AND Language = 'en_US')];

List<String> modifiers;
for (Integer i = 0; i < kavs.size(); i++){
        if (kavs[i].CreatedById != null){
            creator = kavs[i].CreatedById;
            System.debug(creator);
            modifiers.add(creator);
        }
    }
String modifiedBy = String.join(modifiers, ' ,');
```

What am I missing? I've tried a ton of different changes with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `List<String> modifiers;`

But before instanciating as `modifiers= new List<String>();` you are trying to add `modifiers.add(creator);`

So, `modifiers` is null and you are getting

> Attempt to de-reference a null object

Better, declare `List<String> modifiers = new List<String>();` to solve the issue.